# OnKeyListner is not working

Tags: android

Hi Any reply is precious for me and appriciated as well

in one edit text i am setting `onKeyListener` so that when I enter 5 numerics in edittext it will accept n do next process but in samsung galaxy tablet it is not working i am using these lines of code

```
 zipcode.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                System.out.println("setOnKeyListenersetOnKeyListenersetOnKeyListenersetOnKeyListenersetOnKeyListenersetOnKeyListenersetOnKeyListener");
                if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP && zipcode.getText().length() == 5) {
                    System.out.println("OnKeyListener11111");
                    started = true;
                    searchByZipcode(zipcode.getText().toString());
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

 searchByZipcode(zipcode.getText().toString());
```

line takes the text we are writing in to webservice but in galaxy flow doesnt get into onKeylistner can any1 pls help me out thanks

Comment: where else have you tried it?

Answer (score 0):

That's odd. Only in Samsung Galaxys? Is this the full Listener? Maybe you have some other method catching `KeyEvent`s that return `true`?

Try replacing the code for `onKey()` by `onKeyUp()`, which is a `TextView` method:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#onKeyUp%28int,%20android.view.KeyEvent%29

BTW, why do you add `return false;`? Is there any other Listener that requires to handle the `KeyEvent`? If not, I would suggest to change it for `return true;`

> If you handled the event, return true. If you want to allow the event to be handled by the next receiver, return false.

Comment: actually what exactly i want is whenever i write digits in edit text as its lenghth becomes 5 the flow has to get inside onKeyListner so that i can execute rest of my code

Comment: As bigstones asked you, where did you try it that it worked? and you say you have another listener? That is most probably the issue.

Comment: actually what i want is as my edit text length become 5 it will atomatically start working assum in edit text i wrote 1 then in log can t will show me lengh is 1 like dis pls any help me out

Comment: @amit if you want help please consider answering what we are asking you. Also, did you try what I said above?

Comment: Thanks Guy vfor ur precious time and reply i used TextWatcher Class And its working now

Comment: yes i tried that sorry if you felt i did not try, that was not working so i asked you some other help :)